# TINYMCE Read Only affects print button

Tags: tinymce

I have set TinyMCE to read only as below All I want is the Textarea to be read only

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({

        readonly : 1,
        selector: "#editor",

        plugins: "image lists searchreplace fullscreen hr print preview " +
            "anchor code save emoticons directionality spellchecker pagebreak insertdatetime template table",

        toolbar:
            "| print "
    });
</script>
```

I have even tried to make the textarea readonly but this also did not prevent editing.

The code I posted works but also prevents the print button from working. Any way around this as I want just the print button to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE's `readonly` mode works by disabling the Editor itself. For the editor to truly be in a read-only mode, toolbar and menu items would have to be disabled to prevent them from changing the content.

However, it is still possible to trigger TinyMCE's print command programmatically while the Editor itself is in readonly mode.

I've created a Tiny Fiddle demonstrating one way to do this, using Tiny's [execCommand API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editormanager/#execcommand):
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/iOgaab/1

Comment: Brilliant this works, just for clarity the Action in the form section is pointed to dump.php but not used due to the onclick function? Is there a reason you still added the action file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago, I made a solution using JQuery by doing:

```
tinymce.init({

  readonly    : 1, // It will block my buttons :(

  // But....
  setup: ( function ( editor ) {

    //  Fired when the editor skin has been loaded.
    editor.on('SkinLoaded', function(){

      // Change Toolbar styles
      $(".tox-toolbar-overlord").first().removeClass('tox-tbtn--disabled');
      $(".tox-toolbar-overlord").first().attr( 'aria-disabled', 'false' );

      // And activate ALL BUTTONS styles
      $(".tox-toolbar__group button").removeClass('tox-tbtn--disabled');
      $(".tox-toolbar__group button").attr( 'aria-disabled', 'false' );
    })
  })

});
```

NOTE: I just use the full screen button and print,
Sorry 3 years ago I didn't know about this wonderful tool :D